# Cannot replace the file in Kendo React Upload API if same file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, user-experience, kendo-react-ui

Can I know what is the most relevant Upload property in Kendo React which is not allowed to the user to upload the same file again.

[Same file been uploaded twice without asking if to replace the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX5mD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check manually what are in the list of the file upload and then  replace that file with the new one or you can tell the user before uploading by checking if same file name already exists in the list if exists then tell the user that the same name file is already exists in the upload list do you want to replace it if yes you can replace it if no then auto rename the latest file uploaded as filename (1) like counter with it.